# Stop running GWT application in development mode (in eclipse)

Tags: gwt, mode

I'm developing a simple GWT application with eclipse. When I try to run it, it runs in development mode. How I can change its configuration and disable running in development mode?

Comment: Do you want to make the gwt to compile each and every time when you run the application or something else? Try without gwt.codesvr parameter in the url once and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want to disable anything. Instead of running the application as a gwt application deploy the application in tomcat or some other servers. Then it will run as normal web application. Gwt application also a dynamic web project. Nothing extra in it.

From the question I am not able to identify whether you are using any build tool or not. Just incase if you are using maven build tool you have option to maven jetty plugin and execute the mvn jetty:run option.

Answer (score 10):

From eclipse, choose the google tools icon from the toolbar, and then click the red toolbox to compile the code.

When it's compiled, run the project as normal.  From this point, you can either run in development mode by including the gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997 argument on the url, or you can run in production mode by omitting the gwt.codesvr argument.

To be more concise: to run in production mode, just remove the gwt.codesvr argument from the url.  If you get the error that your module "may need to be recompiled," go back to eclipse and choose the red toolbox icon to compile the code again.